# Custom TextField Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, placeholder

I have a requirement for a textfield as shown in the screenshot below. I need to have a placeholder as a "$" symbol that won't disappear when I hit the textfield. Please help me achieve it.

[Custom TextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqq0R.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `UILabel` to the left of your `UITextField` and set its text to be `"$"`. Otherwise, if you have a custom dollar sign you need, I would use a `UIImageView` and set its image to be the image of your dollar sign.